# Cloudformation : is it possible to export current aws configuration as template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I just created Dynamodb table, Lambda function, S3 bucket, etc. I would like to know if there's a way to export this configuration as cloudformation template

Comment: Yes Cloudformer- However The resultant code is pretty verbose, and a little hard to maintain. From scratch templates should not take too long, and you will be able to architect the templates much better, for better long term maintenance.

Comment: Do you have any simple lambda function template ? Because I don't really find any simple one

Answer (score 6):

[CloudFormer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html) is designed to accomplish this, but it does not support Lambda functions, API Gateway and other services. Also, it is clunky,  requires spinning up an EC2 instance and is not designed to create reusable templates - you'll have to adapt them significantly. To my knowledge there is not a service (Amazon or otherwise) to automatically export your resources accurately. It is on the [Cloudcraft](https://cloudcraft.co/) [roadmap](https://trello.com/b/mv14mX1U/cloudcraft-roadmap), but not available yet.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you could use cloudformer to export your aws resources into cloudformation template. Please refer this for example and sample steps . http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html